# Facebook iOS SDK 3.0: how to make comment to existing URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, facebook-ios-sdk

Has anyone tried to use the new Facebook SDK to post a comment to an URL? i tried by using startForPostWithGraphPath like this (code snippet picked from Scrumptious project):

```
id action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setValue:@"test from iOS app" forKey:@"message"];

// Create the request and post the action to my url path.
[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/comments"   
                                   graphObject:action
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 if (error)
                                 {
                                     NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     NSLog(@"ok!!");
                                 }
                             }];
```

it doesn't work neither from Open Graph API explorer. The error i receive is "an unknown error has occurred", code 200. The XXXXXXXX url is the ID of the page i have comments on, i can read them, but not correctly post to them. Maybe the open graph path is wrong?

Comment: _“i receive an error”_ – stating a thing like that without quoting the _actual error message_ – do you really consider this to be helpful …?

Comment: yes, sorry. Posted it too quickly. the error is "unknown", i'll edit it right now.

Comment: hey, any progress? I also want to add a comment on a certain feed news

Answer (score 1):

Hey Friend It's a Good News for you.

I Post the comments and Likes with GraphAPI in IOS

Just write Some code below.

```
         NSMutableDictionary *res = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is my comment", @"message", @"Your api's access Token",@"access_token",nil];
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"XXXXXXXXXX/comments" parameters:res HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (error)
            {
                   NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
            else
            {
                   NSLog(@"ok!!");
            } 
        }];
        XXXXXXXXXX = Id where you want to comment.
```

Note:-

```
Please do not appent https://graph.facebook.com
```

before

```
XXXXXXXXXX/comments
```

Comment: I am trying to comment using following code but always getting error - "no permission"
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/comments",self.strFBPostIDForAction]
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error)
     {
}

Comment: First of all you need to get approved for the permission from the facebook graph api. to post anything on the facebook your facebook app needs to have "publish_actions" permission.

Comment: I have done that as well. Please check my question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597806/iphone-facebook-sdk-fbsdkgraphrequest-not-giving-permission-to-comment-on-post

I have mentioned all the details there.